# os.path.exists returns True even though file doesn't exist on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file, io

I have a strange problem with files in Windows 10. I wrote a Python program that writes some data to some cache files located in `C:\Users\jerfo\AppData\Local\xmr-haystack\xmr-haystack\Cache`. I was able to call `os.makedirs` on the path and write to files within the directory without raising any errors. `os.path.exists` returns `True` for this path. However, when I tried to look at the files in File Explorer, they were not there. I navigated to `C:\Users\jerfo\AppData\Local\`, but I could not find the `xmr-haystack` directory. I confirmed this by attempting to run the command `cd C:\Users\jerfo\AppData\Local\xmr-haystack\xmr-haystack\Cache`, which failed. I have reproduced this problem nearly 10 times with no noticeable changes. I have seen many people with the opposite problem (i.e. `os.path.exists` returns `False` when it shouldn't), but I have not been able to find an instance of a problem similar to mine. Do you all have any insights into what may be causing this problem? Thank you!

Python version: 3.8.6

OS: Windows 10 Home Build 1909

Code in question:

```
import os

cache_dir = 'C:\\Users\\jerfo\\AppData\\Local\\xmr-haystack\\xmr-haystack\\Cache'
file_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, 'cache.json')

os.makedirs(cache_dir, exist_ok=True) # No errors
f = open(file_path, 'w') # No errors
f.write('hello') # No errors
f.close() # Still no errors

print(os.path.exists(cache_dir)) # Prints True, yet the folder doesn't exist
print(os.path.exists(file_path)) # Prints True, yet the file doesn't exist
```

[Link to video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xuQbY37GexZfyqsDRM9_wJDVyFX8RX9h/view?usp=sharing) showing code in action

[Link to screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IV8hYiT_SGeWkPrPvt6PRInSHGUnk_RZ/view?usp=sharing) of the same code demo in video, if unavailable.

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: @MattDMo I added it

Comment: We need more details about your code to be able to help.

Comment: @deponovo what would you like? I just ran that code on my machine two minutes ago and I have described its results.

Comment: Please provide full code, i.e. creating, writng etc. things you described. I just did what you described, the directory is certainly there, available via cmd, explorer and python.

Comment: @pael I updated my post

Comment: Is cache a hidden\system folder ?

Comment: @Mike67 The AppData folder is hidden by default on Windows File Explorer but I enabled viewing hidden folders and was able to navigate inside of it. However, inside AppData, I could not find the folder I created from Python either in the File Explorer or by trying to `cd` inside of it in `cmd`.

Comment: lol ;). Could you try running the whole code. And then for example os.listdir(cache_dir)? Or enter code line by line and checking that in explorer?
Are you running this in some kind fo virtual environment? Or mabye it's loading itself automatically somehow?

Comment: You're probably using the app distribution of Python from the Microsoft Store. The user application data directories are redirected for apps in order to isolate them from each other and the system and facilitate uninstalling them.

Comment: @ErykSun I am using the Python app from the Microsoft Store! That may be the problem. Is there a website for more information on the difference of the Microsoft App version of Python?

Comment: The docs discuss it briefly in [known issues](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#known-issues). For a detailed discussion, see [Understanding how packaged desktop apps run on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes).

Comment: This has wasted me hours... thank you very much, Microsoft! Ugh.